# Statistics - Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

$$\begin{equation}F(x)=\begin{cases}0 &\quad x<-10 \\ 0.25 &   \quad -10\leqslant x <30 \\
0.75 &\quad 30 \leqslant x <50 \\ 1 &\quad 50 \leqslant x \end{cases}\end{equation}$$
$a)\,\, P(X \leqslant 50)$

$b)\,\, P(X \leqslant 40)$

$c)\,\, P(40 \leqslant X \leqslant 60)$

$d)\,\, P(X < 0)$

$e)\,\, P(0\leqslant X < 10)$

$f)\,\, P(-10<X < 10)$

I'm having trouble wrapping my head about how the answers in the back of the book are obtained:

$a)\,\, 1$

$b)\,\, .75$

$c)\,\, .25$

$d)\,\, .25$

$e)\,\, 0$

$f)\,\, 0$

What I do not understand is how to correctly plug in the different values of $X$ and determine the probability of each...in particular when $X$ is between a range of two integers, yet the jumps in probabilities are at different values.

Would anyone care to explain the methodology behind finding these solutions? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, by definition of a c.d.f. $P(X\le x)=F(x)$. Hence,
$P(X\le 50)=F(50)=1$
$P(X \le 40)=F(40)=0.75$
$P(40 \le X \le 60)=P(X\le 60)-P(X < 40)=F(60)-F(40^{-})=1-0.75=0.25$
For the strict inequality, since as $X$ gets close to $0$ from below, it satisfies the $-10<X<30$ condition:
$P(X<0)=0.25$
$P(0\le X < 10)=P(X < 10) - P(X < 0)=0.25-0.25=0$
$P(-10 < X < 10)=P(X<10)-P(X<-10)=0.25-0.25=0$

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I notice that these are all involving less than operators... what if there was another part that asked something like P(X>25)?

Comment: Well, we know that *exactly* one of the following is true: $X\le 25$ or $X>25$. As a result, $P(X\le 25)+P(X>25)=1$.

Comment: I see...so one could solve for it by evaluating 1-P(x≤25) yes? In the case of this problem it would be 1-.25 = .75 correct?

Comment: That is correct. :-)

Comment: Although the _numerical answer_ for $P(40\leq X \leq 60)$ happens to be correct in this instance, it is highly misleading to tell a beginner that $$P(40\leq X \leq 60) = P(X\leq 60) - P(X\leq 40) = F(60)-F(40)$$ instead of $$P(40\leq X \leq 60) = P(X\leq 60) - P(X< 40) = F(60) - F(40^-).$$ It is inappropriate to stimulate the development of bad habits....

Comment: Dilip, what is the difference between F(40) and F(40-)? Thank you

Comment: In this instance, the two quantities have the same numerical value. But suppose you were asked for the probability that $-10 \leq X \leq 30$. Following Daniel Littlewood's method would give $$P(-10\leq X\leq 30)=F(30)-F(-10)=0.75-0.25=0.5$$ which is _wrong_. What you need to find is $P(X\leq 30)-P(X<-10)$ where the latter value $P(X<-10)$ is given by $$P(X<-10)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0,\epsilon>0}F(-10-\epsilon),$$ that is the _limiting value_ of $F(x)$ as $x$ approaches $-10$ _from the left_. Since $F(x) is _discontinuous_ at $-10$, this is _not_ the same as the limit from the right. (continued)

Comment: (continued) The value of $F(x)$ at any $x_0$ is defined as the limiting value as $x$ approaches $x_0$ _from the right_. If $F(x)$ is _continuous_ at $x_0$, we get the same limit if we approach $x_0$ from the left. (This happens at $x_0 = 40$ in your question). But if $F(x)$ is _discontinuous_ at $x_0$, then the limit from the _left_ gives $P(X<x_0)$ while the limit from the _right_ gives $F(x_0) = P(X\leq x_0)$. The former quantity is sometimes denoted as $F(x_0^-)$ meaning limit from the left. Note that $$F(x_0)-F(x_0^-)=P(X=x_0).$$

Comment: Dilip is right, I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The $F(x)$ given to you is the **cumulative** distribution function. Before $-10$, it is $0$. **At** $-10$, it suddenly **jumps** to $0.25$, and stays there for a while. So there must be a weight of $0.25$ **at** $x=-10$. That is, $\Pr(X=-10)=0.25$.

Similarly, there is a sudden jump from $0.25$ to $0.75$ at $30$. Thus $\Pr(X=30)=0.50$.

Finally, $\Pr(X=50)=0.25$.

So we have the complete probability distribution function of $X$. The random variable $X$ takes on the values $-10$, $30$, and $50$, with probabilities $0.25$, $0.50$, and $0.25$. Now you can answer any question.

We could also answer the questions "algebraically." The only nuisance is that, because of the jumps, we need to carefully distinguish between $\lt$ and $\le$, also between $\gt$ and $\ge$.

Here is a sample. For (e), we want $\Pr(0\le x\lt 10)$. This is $\Pr(X\lt 10)-\Pr(X\lt 0)$.

Look at the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ of $X$. Just short of $10$, it has value $0.25$. Just short of $0$, it has value $0.25$. Subtract: the result is $0$.

But it is intuitively clearer to observe that $X$ "takes on" no values between $0$ and $10$.

**Remark:** Occasionally, one even bumps into random variables that have a character which is a hybrid of the discrete and the continuous. For example, after the weight of $0.25$ at $x=-10$, the cumulative distribution function could after that climb smoothly to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a step function that jumps at $-10$, $30$, and $50$. So at these steps you gain the increments indicated by $F$: $0.25, 0.75-0.25 = 0.5,$ and $1 - 0.75 = 0.25$ (the difference between before and after). Note also that if you hit any of the thresholds, you will get the full increase, which matters to distinguish $<$ from $\leq$ in the questions (c., eg, (e) below as you have a right end of the interval of $< 10$, not $\leq 10$). For instance,

(a) $\mathbf{P}(X \leq 50)=1$ as you jumped $50$ to reach the final $1$
(c) $\mathbf{P}(40 \leq X < 60)= 0.25$ as you jumped at 50 by 0.25
(e) $\mathbf{P}(0 \leq X < 10) = 0$ as you last jumped at $-10$, and will again at $10$.